# Annotation Processor Not Running

Tags: java, java-8, annotation-processing

### Project 1 (annotation project):

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0.1'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Annotation**

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Table {
    String value();
    String[] ignoreColumns() default {};
}
```

**Processor**

```
@AutoService(TableProcessor.class)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.github.ahuangJM.annotations.Table")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class TableProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        System.out.println("init hit!");
        super.init(processingEnv);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        final Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Processing...");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**\resources\META-INF\javax.annotation.processing.Processor**

```
org.example.processors.TableProcessor
```

### Project 2 (annotation project consumer):

**Annotation Consumer**

```
@Table("user-info")
public class UserInfo {
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation files("REDACTED\\code-generator-annotation.jar")
    annotationProcessor files("REDACTED\\code-generator-annotation.jar")

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This should be a very simple annotation processor just printing debugging statements.
This all seems correct to me, but `process()` is not running when I build/run project 2. I have tried overriding `getSupportedVersion()` and `getSupportedAnnotationTypes()` as well. That didn't do anything. Also tried without `@AutoService`, that didn't change anything as well.

**EDIT:** why am i can getting the `print()` and/or `printMessage()` statement?

Comment: Is your question is, why you are not seeing the print statement in init & process methods?

Comment: Yup! Mostly why am I not getting the printMessage().

Answer (score 1):

```
@AutoService(TableProcessor.class)
```

should be

```
@AutoService(Processor.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@AutoService(TableProcessor.class)
```

should be

```
@AutoService(AbstractProcessor.class) or @AutoService(Processor.class)
```

@autoservice(X) means you implement X, but i see a class or interface Processor in your question, so you have to be sure what implement what but your @autoservice first is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

> *@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)*

should be

> *@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is won't change anything. This can only break a program rather than fix anything.

Comment: Retention is rather like access modifiers, telling someone to make a field public is inconsequential, but telling them to make it private may have consequences. Runtime retention also means source retention, but not vise-versa.