# Gradle java Annotation Process API is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, annotations

Gradle java Annotation Process API is not working

#### Information

My Enviorment

```
gradle 7.6.1
Java 19
Spring Boot 3.0.6
```

My Module struct

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
├── current-module
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── classes
│   │   ├── generated
│   │   ├── jacoco
│   │   ├── libs
│   │   ├── reports
│   │   ├── resolvedMainClassName
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   ├── test-results
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       └── test
└── untitled.iml
```

Main module bundle.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'jacoco'
}

bootJar.enabled = false

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

subprojects {
    group = 'com.hello'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '19'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
    }

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    }
}
```

current-module bundle.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.hello'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1'
}
```

#### My Source Code

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

    CustomClass customClass();
}
```

```java
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class CustomProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return Set.of(CustomAnnotation.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        System.out.println("Checking Annotation Process");
    }


}
```

#### What i Want to do.

I want to create .java file when compile time without using other module
So I use Java Annotation Process API.
All the Articles and Question that i found use multi-modules, it only use the java annunciation process for certain multi-module.
But, I don't want to use this specific module. I want to handle it in the current module.

#### Problem

When I compile it, It create `build/classes/java/main/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` This one is create very success.
But CustomProcessor is not working, can't see print anything.

#### Knowledge Which I understand.

Annotation processing is carried out over several rounds.

1. The Java Compiler performs compilation. Java Compiler know about Annotation Processor in advance
2. Perform the annotation processors that are not running
3. The compiler makes sure that all annotation processors are running, and if not, it does so repeatedly.
4. when use custom annotation process, In `resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file needed. and In this file, write my annotationProcess name (I use `auto-service` library for writing it)

#### Conclusion

How to work CustomProcessor and how to create file in module?

#### what did I try

- Gradle Clean and build
- [Annotation processor not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65733841/annotation-processor-not-executed)
- [Annotation Processor Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299528/annotation-processor-not-running)